# Mostrar en Vista Laravel los registros de una relación Muchos a Muchos (ManyToMany)

Tags: laravel

Agradecido de antemano, actualmente estoy buscando mostrar los registros de 2 tablas con relación ManyToMany donde se crea la tabla pivot, las relaciones ya están hechas funcionan al hacer la prueba con tinker.

```
>>> $productore = fgmsyt\tb_productore::findOrFail(6)
=> fgmsyt\tb_productore {#2933
     id: 6,
     cnombproductor: "Nombredeprueba",
     capeproductor: "Aprellidodeprueba",
     ncedula: 11123123,
     cemail: "correodeprueba@gmail.com",
     ctelf: "04121234567",
     created_at: "2018-10-18 18:10:50",
     updated_at: "2018-11-12 10:45:55",
   }
>>> $productore->tb_identpryt
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2946
     all: [
       fgmsyt\tb_identpryt {#2951
         id: 8,
         numero_pry: "212121",
         nombre_pry: "Proyecto de Prueba Para El Sistema",
         descrip_pry: "este proyecto es una prueba",
         act_econom_pry: "actividad economica de prueba",
         registrado: true,
         id_letra_rif: 1,
         id_ciudad: 163,
         id_estado: 10,
         id_municipio: 109,
         id_parroquia: 352,
         numer_rif: 12123123,
         numer_ident_rif_pry: 1,
         codigo_situr: "0001010101",
         codigo_sunagro: "0123412",
         direccion: "LOS MANGOS",
         telefono: "04261231212",
         created_at: "2018-11-06 16:58:19",
         updated_at: "2018-11-06 16:58:19",
         fech_ini: "2018-02-01",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#2950
           tb_productore_id: 6,
           tb_identpryt_id: 8,
         },
       },
     ],
   }
>>> $productore = fgmsyt\tb_identpryt::findOrFail(8)
=> fgmsyt\tb_identpryt {#2949
     id: 8,
     numero_pry: "212121",
     nombre_pry: "Proyecto de Prueba Para El Sistema",
     descrip_pry: "este proyecto es una prueba",
     act_econom_pry: "actividad economica de prueba",
     registrado: true,
     id_letra_rif: 1,
     id_ciudad: 163,
     id_estado: 10,
     id_municipio: 109,
     id_parroquia: 352,
     numer_rif: 12123123,
     numer_ident_rif_pry: 1,
     codigo_situr: "0001010101",
     codigo_sunagro: "0123412",
     direccion: "LOS MANGOS",
     telefono: "04261231212",
     created_at: "2018-11-06 16:58:19",
     updated_at: "2018-11-06 16:58:19",
     fech_ini: "2018-02-01",
   }
>>> $productore->tb_productore
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2937
     all: [
       fgmsyt\tb_productore {#2930
         id: 6,
         cnombproductor: "Nombredeprueba",
         capeproductor: "Apellidodeprueba",
         ncedula: 11123123,
         cemail: "correodeprueba@gmail.com",
         ctelempleado: "04121234567",
         created_at: "2018-10-18 18:10:50",
         updated_at: "2018-11-12 10:45:55",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#2926
           tb_identpryt_id: 8,
           tb_productore_id: 6,
         },
       },
     ],
   }
>>>
```

Las pruebas con tinker funcionan, pero haciendo solo un `findOrFail(id)`.

lo que necesito hacer es un `all()` para traerme a todos los registros con su relación y en la visitar hacer el `foreach` y mostrar los campos que necesite, ejemplo: `cnombproductor, capeproductor, capeproductor`.

Cuando hago la prueba que necesito con tinker `>>> $productore = fgmsyt\tb_productore::all()` trae todos los registros de esa tabla, pero cuando ejecuto la relación: `>>> $productore->tb_identpryt` 
sale un error que dice:

> Exception with message 'Property [tb_identpryt] does not exist on this
>   collection instance.'

Modelo **tb_productore**:

```
<?php

namespace fgmsyt;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tb_productore extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['cnombproductor', 'capeproductor', 'ncedula', 'cemail', 'ctelf'];



    public function tb_identpryt()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(tb_identpryt::class);
    }


}
```

Modelo: tb_identpryt

```
<?php

namespace fgmsyt;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tb_identpryt extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable = ['numero_pry','nombre_pry','descrip_pry', 'act_econom_pry','registrado', 'id_letra_rif', 'numer_rif', 'id_estado', 'id_ciudad', 'id_municipio', 'id_parroquia', 'numer_ident_rif_pry', 'codigo_situr', 'codigo_sunagro', 'direccion', 'telefono','fech_ini'];


    public function tb_productore()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(tb_productore::class);
    }
}
```

He estado buscando por muchas paginas, Foros y aun no doy con la solución, agradecería si alguien me puede guiar o decir por que es el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las correcciones realizadas estaré más atento a las siguientes preguntas que realice en la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

el error es porque no puedes acceder de esta forma:

```
$productore->tb_identpryt;
```

a elementos de una Colección... Tendrías que acceder:

```
$productore[0]->tb_identpryt; //Para el elemento 0
$productore[1]->tb_identpryt; //Para el elemento 1
```

Como bien dices, debes recorrer la Colección con foreach en la vista:

```
@foreach ($productore as $value)
{{ $value->tb_identpryt }} 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Gracias amigo logre resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias amigo me ayudo a resolver, lo que hice fue hacer dos `@foreach`uno para recorrer la primera variable que se envía `$productores` 
el otro interno para recorrer la relación y buscar el campo que necesitaba.

```
@foreach ($productores as $productor)
      <td>{{ $productor-> ncedula }}</td>
         ...
         ...
           @foreach ($productor->tb_identpryt as $value)
                <td>{{ $value->nombre_pry }}</td>
           @endforeach
@endforeach
```

funciona bien ahora toca buscar como editar eso registros. y resolver que la vista se vea bien.